# Why would a steam rice cooker suddenly make my dad sick?

Tags: equipment, rice

My dad has owned the same rice cooker for years and it always worked fine. Recently, every time he makes rice, which is all it has ever been used for, he gets sick to his stomach almost immediately after eating it. No amount of cleaning and rinsing to make sure all soap is out of it makes any difference. It also doesn't matter what brand of rice, even the same ones we have always used. What is the problem? The unit seems to work just fine.

Comment: Can you describe what's actually wrong with the rice? Bubbly and making someone sick isn't very specific. What do you mean by bubbly? Also, has anything else changed? Is he okay with rice cooked elsewhere?

Comment: Also, is he eating the rice immediately or does the rice sit for some time before being eaten?

Comment: Is anyone else feeling ill from eating the same rice?

Comment: Could it be the fault of something else he commonly eats with the rice?

Comment: Can you just try cooking the rice in a different pan and seeing if that works?

Comment: How about taking him to the doctor and checking for allergies?

Comment: I'm going ahead and finishing closing this, since it's obviously pretty tough to answer based on the current detail. If it were just your dad getting sick, it could be a lot of human things (a couple bad batches, now he expects it and it's psychological); you mentioned it getting bubbly which could possibly be a real difference but you didn't give enough detail to really tell for sure.

Answer (score 2):

The big question is: what changed? Some possibilities:

- The rice cooker isn't being cleaned properly. Doesn't seem likely that the residue on an even poorly-cleaned metal pan would significantly contaminate the results.
- The water or other cooking ingredients. Doesn't seem likely since the water is probably the same stuff you drink, and generally there aren't any other ingredients when using a rice cooker.
- Your dad. Has he developed some sort of allergy or reaction to the rice?

Comment: To check on the allergy-thing: you seem to have tried everthing cooker-related and everything type-of-rice-related. Have you tried cooking the rice in a pot? If that STILL causes the reaction: yes, most likely some sort of allergy.

Comment: @Layna excellent idea.

Comment: *being cleaned properly* includes making sure there is no residu from the cleaning fluids left on the cooker. Did you change those, maybe?

Comment: The OP said "It also doesn't matter what brand of rice, even the same ones we have always used." suggesting that they've tried at least a few.